# Firebase Cloud Function while calling Third Party APIs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am planning to use Firebase for my next mobile app project. I am a little confused about this section of pricing

[image: Firebase Pricing for Cloud Function]

My application will be heavily relying on third-party APIs, where we will call API from firebase cloud function

Mobile App <--------> Firebase Cloud Functions <--------> Third Party APIs

Most APIs execution time heavily depends on what it takes the third party to respond. I am not sure how this is going to impact Cloud Function's GB Second and CPU Seconds. What's your suggestion of using firebase in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You will be paying for the time it takes the API to respond to requests before the function can terminate cleanly.  The falls under CPU-seconds billing.

The exception to this is if the API lets you provide a webhook (HTTP) callback, which will be invoked with the results of the request.  You will then be paying for the invocation of that function, and not the time between invocations.

Comment: API doesnt provide a webhook so we cant follow approach you mentioned. It seems using firebase is not a good option for us.

Comment: "Not good" is a matter of estimating the actual cost vs. other similar providers of serverless backend functionality.  I think it might be hard to find something less expensive.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please mark it as correct.